# jenkins acess environment variables in environment declaration

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

So I have an environment in a Jenkins declarative pipeline script that looks something like this:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        PATH1 = 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents'
        PATH2 = '${env.PATH1}\\more_stuff'
    }
    // etc...
```

But when I try to access PATH2 in anything, it transcribes the literal "${env.PATH1}" into it rather that the environment variable PATH1.

I have tried `${env.PATH1}`, `${PATH1}`, `%PATH1%`, but none of them work. How do I access environment variables while declaring other environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you are trying to use [Groovy string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

Groovy string interpolation is only performed on double quoted strings, not single quoted strings.

I believe what you want is

```
PATH2 = "${env.PATH1}\\more_stuff"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. None of the Jenkins environment examples had "one env variable inside another" so I couln't figure it out